# How to use remote:true in rails using radio_button/ radio button no mark when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-tabs

I want to make a radio button that when selected, it will make a new tab (bootstrap panel with nav tabs) and in that tab, i can register details corresponding to the selected radio button. for example, when i choose fruits radio button, it will make a new tab and when i go to that tab, i can input it's name, weight, etc... and when i select meat radio button, it will make a new tab again.

This is my preferred codes:

```
<input type="radio" name="id" value="<%= row.id %>" onclick="document.location.href='<%= path_name %>" data-remote="true">
```

But sadly, the data-remote="true" is not working and it doesnt make a new tab.

I found a way-around to implement it using this code:

```
<% @foo.each do |row| %>
    <%= link_to(pathname, :remote => "true") do %>
        <input type="radio" name="id" value="<%= row.id %>">
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, using this code, the radio button can't be selected(there is no mark that indicates that it is selected).

Can anyone please help me how to either make the remote="true" work or make the selection of radio button seen.

Comment: jQuery UJS works with forms or links - not single inputs. Its a utility - not a complete replacement for writing javascript yourself. Just write a handler in javascript that you bind to the `change` event on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UJS works with forms or links - not single inputs. However writing an event handler with jQuery is really trivial.

```
<%= radio_button_tag :id, row.id, data: { href: path_name }, class: 'remote-input' %>
```

Use `data` attributes to pass data to the the client side instead of inline `onclick` handlers.

```
# place this in 
# app/assets/javascripts/
$(document).on("change",".remote-input", function(){
  var uri = $(this).data('href');
  if (uri){
    window.location = uri;
  }
  // or whatever you want to do.
});
```